# Error connecting to MongoDB on Render.com: MongooseServerSelectionError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern, render.com

I'm trying to deploy my Node.js application on Render.com, but I'm encountering an error when connecting to MongoDB. Here are the details:

- I'm using MongoDB with Mongoose in my Node.js application.
- Locally, the application connects to MongoDB without any issues.
- However, when deploying to Render.com, I'm getting the following error: "Failed to connect to MongoDB: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017".
- I have verified that the MongoDB service is running and accessible.
- I've tried using both the **`mongodb://127.0.0.1/iNotebook`** and **`mongodb://localhost:27017/iNotebook`** URIs, but the error persists.
- I have also checked the firewall settings on Render.com and made sure that the MongoDB port (27017) is open.

I'm not sure why the connection is failing on Render.com but works fine locally. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the link to both my Frontend and Backend repository:

https://github.com/aarontauro/iNotebook-Frontend

https://github.com/aarontauro/iNotebook-Backend

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Well you are trying to connect MongoDB from your machine, and render.com cannot access to your machine, , you'll need to specify the hostname or IP address of the remote MongoDB server, like using mongoDB Atlas

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Ill try this and let u know with the update